# Assist with: Interface Builder was unable to determine the type of "FileName.xib"

Tags: xcode, xib

I'm working on source code for an IPA another developer is building for me. Hadn't made any adjustments as of yet because, knowing how temperamental the environment can be, wanted to do a test build first of the freshly unpacked project. I'm getting two errors right off the bat, saying:
Interface Builder was unable to determine the type of "FileName.xib"
("FileName" is a placeholder for the two files represented. Error message is the same for both.)
I've done some research and found this could be an XCode version issue between the developer and myself, but the developer won't be available to ask until next week, and I've got some critical testing to do this weekend. Need to get this one resolved as soon as possible.

Any advice would be helpful.

Thanks.

Cayce